# Is there a way to ignore not permitted access when executing shell in Applescript?

Tags: shell, applescript

So I wanted to use a `find` command in shell in my AppleScript. I wanted to search my entire disk for a certain filetype so I did something like this:

```
set theItems to do shell script "find / -name '*.mp3'" with administrator privileges
set theItems to paragraphs of theItems
repeat with theFile in theItems
    --some code that process every file here
end repeat
```

The problem is that, even though I added the extra `with administrator privileges`, some files are still owned by the system and I don't have access to them. In my loop, I have some code in place that will deal with those lines though.

Is there a way to just ignore those?

Comment: You can add `2>/dev/null; exit 0` to the end of your `find` command to not have the  `Permission denied` lines not show in the results. Also you might what to add `find` and whatever _application_ you are running the _code_ in to **Full Disk Access** in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `find` command gets errors accessing some files/directories, it's going to report errors and exit with an error status; when `do shell script` sees that error, it throws an AppleScript-level error of its own.

You can make the script always succeed by adding `|| true` to the end. In shell language, that means "if the `find` command fails (exits with error status), run `true`, which always succeeds, so the overall script succeeds.

I don't think it's necessary, but it might also be good to suppress the error messages that `find` prints by adding `2>/dev/null` (although `do shell script` seems to ignore these messages as long as the overall command succeeds).

```
set theItems to do shell script "find / -name '*.mp3' 2>/dev/null || true" with administrator privileges
```

I do have a warning, however: this suppresses *all* errors from `find`, not just permissions errors, so if something else goes wrong you won't be notified.